# CandleStick Chart of vue-echarts is not rendering on reloading the page in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli-3, echarts

I am integrating the candle stick chart by using vue-echarts library in my vuejs project. First time, when I redirect to the page it works perfectly but when I reload the page it shows error

> "Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of
>   undefined"

and chart disappears. Please see the code in below code sandbox link. My project has implemented with Vue CLI-3. I am not getting where I am doing wrong.

#### These are the below versions in my project.

Vue Version: 2.6.10
echarts: 4.2.1
vue-echarts: 4.0.3

**Demo Here**
Here is the demo of my code [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-516m8?fontsize=14)

Any help wil be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After so many tries, I finally ended up with the solution. I am missing some components due to which chart is not working. Please check the codesandbox link. I have added the missing components: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-2bmdv?fontsize=14

Hope, it helps for other developers also. Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your sandbox link ? I got the same issue as you.